# How Do I Install Gluon Plugin in Apache NetBeans 9.0?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

Is there a way to install Gluon Plugin in Apache NetBeans 9.0? If not, how can I add additional support to NetBeans?

Comment: The Gluon plugin works on NetBeans 9.0 and 10.0, but you need to install the Gradle plugin first, manually from [here](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/releases/tag/v2.0.2).

Comment: Thanks , I install gluon plugin in apache  netbeans 9.0 i can work now

Comment: Hey there! I have edited your question and title to hopefully make it clearer for others to answer. Please let me know if I have misinterpreted your meaning. Take care :-)